# why can't I call HTML in ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i have 1 error when i try to use html in jquery to add product quantity to cart but cant add even though click event is caught.when the click event is done, get the value in the APIController with Id "cart-number", it cannot be called.here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cart-btn").click(function(){
        var color_id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").attr("data-color");
        var color_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".color").text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find(".quantity").text();
        
        var product_name = $("#detail-title").text();
        var product_id = $("#detail-title").attr("data-Id");
        var price = $("#detail-price").attr("data-value");
        
           $.ajax({
            url:"/PhoneAccessories/api/addtocart",
            type:"GET",
            data:{
                product_id:product_id,
                color_id:color_id,
                quantity:quantity,
                product_name:product_name,
                price:price,
                color_name:color_name
            },
            success: function(value){
                $("#cart-number").html("<span>"+value+"</span>");
            }
        })
    
    });
});
```

this is my APIController:

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping("api/")
    @SessionAttributes({"email","cart"})
    public class APIController {
        @Autowired
        EmployeeService employeeService;
        
        @GetMapping("addtocart")
        public String AddToCart(@RequestParam int product_id,@RequestParam int color_id,@RequestParam int quantity,@RequestParam String product_name,@RequestParam String price,@RequestParam String color_name,HttpSession httpSession) {
            
            if(httpSession.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
                List<ProductCart> productCarts = new ArrayList<ProductCart>();
                ProductCart carts = new ProductCart();
                carts.setProduct_id(product_id);
                carts.setColor_id(color_id);
                carts.setQuantity(1);
                carts.setProduct_name(product_name);
                carts.setPrice(price);
                carts.setColor_name(color_name);
                productCarts.add(carts);
                httpSession.setAttribute("cart", productCarts);
                List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
                return listCart.size()+ "";
            }else {
                List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
                int location = CheckProductAlreadyExists(product_id, color_id, httpSession);
                if(location == -1) {
                    
                    ProductCart carts = new ProductCart();
                    carts.setProduct_id(product_id);
                    carts.setColor_id(color_id);
                    carts.setQuantity(1);
                    carts.setProduct_name(product_name);
                    carts.setPrice(price);
                    carts.setColor_name(color_name);
                    listCart.add(carts);
                }else {
                    
                    int newQuantity = listCart.get(location).getQuantity()+1;
                    listCart.get(location).setQuantity(newQuantity);
                }
                return listCart.size() +"";
                
            }
            
            
        }
        private int CheckProductAlreadyExists(int product_id,int color_id,HttpSession httpSession) {
            List<ProductCart> listCart = (List<ProductCart>) httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
            for(int i=0;i<listCart.size();i++) {
                if(listCart.get(i).getProduct_id()== product_id && listCart.get(i).getColor_id() ==color_id ) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

here is the jsp details page:

```
<body>
    <section id="detail-page">

        <nav>
            <div id="check" class="logo">
                <img id="image-logo" src='<c:url value="/resources/Image/YOP.png"/>' />
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/PhoneAccessories/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Products">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Review">Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Servises">Servises</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"><div id="cart-number"><span>${NumberOfProduct}</span></div></i> 
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${fc != null}">
                        <a id="first-char" href="login/"> ${fc} </i></a>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <a href="/PhoneAccessories/login/"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

            </div>

        </nav>


    </section>
    
    <!-- Detail Product -->
    
    <div id="container-detail" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="product-category" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            <div>
                <span id="product-category-titile">Product Catalogue</span>
            </div>
                <ul id="product-category-ul">
                <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                <!-- 
                    <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
                        <li><a href="#">${category}</a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                 -->
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                        <img id="image-detail" src='<c:url value="/resources/Image/products/${product.getProduct_image()}"/>' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                        <h4 id="detail-title" data-Id="${product.getProduct_id()}" >${product.getProduct_name()}</h4>
                        <h5 id="detail-price" data-value="${product.getProduct_price()}" >${product.getProduct_price()}</h5>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Color</td>
                                    <td>Quantity</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <c:forEach var="detailProduct" items="${product.getProduct_Details()}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="color" data-color="${detailProduct.getProduct_Color().getColor_id()}" >${detailProduct.getProduct_Color().getColor_name()}</td>
                                        <td class="quantity" data-quantity="${detailProduct.getQuantity()}" >${detailProduct.getQuantity()}</td>
                                        <td><button id="product-button" class="cart-btn">shop now</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <h5>Description</h5>
                <span>${product.getDescription_product()}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Footer-->

    <footer>
        <div class="footer_main">
            <div class="tag">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>123/Colombo/Sri
                    Lanka</a> <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>+94 12 345
                    6789</a> <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>contact@gmail.com</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <h1>Get Help</h1>
                <a href="#" class="center">FAQ</a> <a href="#" class="center">Shipping</a>
                <a href="#" class="center">Returns</a> <a href="#" class="center">Payment
                    Options</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <h1>Our Stores</h1>
                <a href="#" class="center">Sri Lanka</a> <a href="#" class="center">USA</a>
                <a href="#" class="center">India</a> <a href="#" class="center">Japan</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <h1>Follw Us</h1>
                <div class="social_link">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                        class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                        class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                        class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tag">
                <h1>Newsletter</h1>
                <div class="search_bar">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="You email id here">
                    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
</body>
```